# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized) and Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Tags: reactjs

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized) and Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (localStorage.getItem('user-info')) {
    Navigate.push('/nxt');
  }
}, []);
async function login() {
  console.warn(Username, Password);
  let item = { Username, Password };
  let result = await fetch('http://api.kyc365pro.com:6061/login', {
    method: 'POST',
    mode: 'no-cors',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Accept: '*/*',
    },

    body: JSON.stringify(item),
  });
  result = await result.json(); //errors shows here
  console.log(result);
  localStorage.setItem('user-info', JSON.stringify(result));
  Navigate.push('/nxt');
}

return (
  <div>
    <h1>Login page</h1>
    <label>Username</label>
    <input
      type='text'
      placeholder='Username'
      onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}
    />
    <br></br>
    <label>Password</label>
    <input
      type='password'
      placeholder='Password'
      onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
    />
    <br />
    <button onClick={login}>Login</button>
  </div>
);
}

export default Login
```

Comment: Without more info it seems like the API is saying you have invalid credentials. Does the API you send the request to expect the data you send to be "Username" and "Password", it might be case senstive, or expecting other params? Does the request work using something insomnia or postman (to rule out API problem)?

Comment: Your credentials are not recognized as valid by the API. You should post the code responsible for handling the `/login` end point.